# Displaying form at the same location as parent of calling button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a UserControl with a button in a panel which is on the UserControl (this is part of a custom calendar set up with a TableLayoutPanel and the UserControl is what displays the contents of each day in the calendar).  Clicking the button displays a dialog. I want the dialog to display at the same location as the UserControl.  I have the StartPosition property for the dialog set to "Manual".

```
 dlgStatuses DlgStatuses = new dlgStatuses(this);
        ucDate ucParent = (ucDate)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent; //This is the UserControl
        int x = PointToScreen(ucParent.Location).X;
        int y = PointToScreen(ucParent.Location).Y;
        DlgStatuses.Location = new Point(x, y);
        DlgStatuses.ShowDialog();
```

This is not working as desired.  I've tried PointToClient and it fails as well.  I've also tried this and it fails:

```
dlgStatuses DlgStatuses = new dlgStatuses(this);
        ucDate ucParent = (ucDate)((Button)sender).Parent.Parent;            
        DlgStatuses.Location = ucParent.Location;
        DlgStatuses.ShowDialog();
```

So what I'm looking for is to have DlgStatuses display at the same location as ucParent.

Comment: If that code is running in the UserControl, then it would just be `DlgStatuses.Location = this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);`

Comment: @LarsTech - That's too easy, simple and elegant a solution to use.  I was hoping for something far more difficult to implement and more subject to failure..